# vba start stop timers?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to start and stop two timers in my excel worksheet. This is what i have:

When worksheet is opened, this module is triggered:

```
Sub SetOpenTimer()

OpenTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
Application.OnTime OpenTimer, "StartTimerShutdownForm"

End Sub
```

After 10 seconds (in this example), the sub `startimershutdownform` is triggered:

```
Sub StartTimerShutdownForm()

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

This displays a userform where a message is displayed. In the initialize sub in the Userform a sub `setformtimer` is triggered:

```
Sub setFormTimer()

FormTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
Application.OnTime FormTimer, "Shutdown"

End Sub
```

If this timer in `setformtimer` ends, the sub `shutdown` is triggerd
this sub closes the workbook, but in the Userform there is a button for the user to cancel the `setformtimer`:

```
Sub stopFormTimer()

Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=FormTimer, _
Procedure:="setOpenTimer", Schedule:=False

End Sub
```

This suppose to stop the `setformtimer`, but it does not work.
When this timer is stopped, it suppose to restart the timer that is triggered when the document is being opened, so it all restarts, but the stop timer code does not work.

In the module where  `stopFormTimer`, `setFormTimer` and `StartTimerShutdownForm` is located, at the top I declare these

```
Dim OpenTimer As Date
Dim FormTimer As Date
```

What am i missing here? Why cant i stop the timer and restart the first timer?

Comment: It could be because Excel is not in `Ready-Mode` becasue the Form is displayed? More info in `Application.OnTime, LatestTime parameter`.

Comment: Dont understand the ready-mode. Based on this, how would i solve my issue? I can not find anything about "ready-mode" that explain how i set it to ready... it seems other can make timers stop.. dont know why my excel would not be in "ready-mode".

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have different proc names in the two subs. They must match. I'd try:

```
Sub setFormTimer()
    FormTimer  = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=FormTimer, Procedure:="Shutdown", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub stopFormTimer()
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=FormTimer, Procedure:="Shutdown", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Sadly this did not help. I have tried your code. I still get the same error. Can not stop the timer.